# Openstack heat software config on ubuntu 12.04.5 doesn't execute

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, openstack, cloud-init, openstack-heat

I'm trying to use openstack heat software config on ubuntu 12.04.5 server like example file below.
This works great when the server i build is ubuntu 16 but when I try to do this on ubuntu 12.04.5 the script in the software config does not get executed at boot time.

I know I can use the regular user_data but that is not the solution I am trying to go for.

```
resources:

  boot_script:
    type: OS::Heat::SoftwareConfig
    properties:
      config: |
        #!/bin/bash
       touch /tmp/test.txt
        # ...

  server_init:
    type: OS::Heat::MultipartMime
    properties:
      parts:
      - config: {get_resource: boot_script}

  server:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      # flavor, image etc  (ubuntu 12.04.5 image)
      user_data_format: SOFTWARE_CONFIG
      user_data: {get_resource: server_init}
```